# View PDF Documents like Magazines in HTML5

Tags: gratis, pdf, html, pdf-viewer

I would like to take a PDF document and view it like a Magazine in HTML5. My requirements are,

- Flip affects
- Gratis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out FlipHTML5. It meets both your requirements of,

- having flip affects
- being free

## [FlipHTML5](http://fliphtml5.com/)

> FLIP HTML5 is a Interactive html5 digital publishing platform that
> makes it easy to create interactive digital publications, including
> magazines, catalogs, newspapers, books, and more online; Create HTML5
> flipbook from PDF to view on iPhone, iPad and Android devices.
>
> [image: FlipHTML5]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.paperturn.com/us

They got a free trial, without adds, and it actually looks very nice!